# (java) Is it possible to read from user 2 values, one string and the other double in the same line?

Tags: java, loops

The idea of this program is to keep reading from the user a product name and it's price in the same line till the user type stop, and then calculate if the user has enough money. But I'm getting an error after inputting two lines, that what I wrote (please help):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AA_152 {
public static void main (String[] args ){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How much money do you have? ");
double money = input.nextDouble();

double price;
double total = 0;
String product;
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please, Insert the items in the invoice (the name product 
and its price):\n"
        + "Insert \"stop\" as the name product to finish your input ");
while (!input1.next().equals("stop")){
product = input1.next();
price = input1.nextDouble();
total += price;
}
if (total <= money)
System.out.println("you have enough money");
else
    System.out.println("you don\'t have enough money");

}    
}
```

this is the error I get when I run the program:

```
How much money do you have? 100
Please, Insert the items in the invoice (the name product and its price):
Insert "stop" as the name product to finish your input 
orange 12.200
water 15.400
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at AlaaAwad_152306.main(AlaaAwad_152306.java:27)
C:\Users\Alaa\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Comment: Why do you want to ask the name of the product ? because you never use it , so it's useless no ?

Comment: well, I'm gonna use it later because I also want the program to display the name product of the lowest price. I will add that later.

Comment: I just want to know how to make the program to take 2 values in the same line (String, double) without crashing .

Comment: You aren't getting "an error", you are getting a *specific* error. Post it.

Comment: Please be more specific. If not, we cannot help you.

Comment: after I enter 2 lines the program stop working .(the message error included above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args ){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Q1
        System.out.print("How much money do you have? ");
        double money = Double.valueOf(input.nextLine());
        HashMap<String,Double> products = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        //Q2
        double total = 0;
        String[] product;
        String line="";
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please,insert the items in the invoice (this typo : 'name-price'):\n"
                + "Insert \"stop\" as the name product to finish your input ");
        while (!(line = input1.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
            product = line.split("-");
            products.put(product[0], Double.valueOf(product[1]));
            total += Double.valueOf(product[1]);
            System.out.println("Another one ?");
        }
        if (total <= money){
            System.out.println("you have enough money for "+products);
        }else{
            System.out.println("you don\'t have enough money for "+products);
        }
        input1.close();
    }
```

So somes improvements :

- I add a HashMap to store the pairs productName/Price, HashMap is the most convenient way to store pairs
- In the while condition 1 things are made : store the input in `line` and check if it's "stop" because with your code you need 2 inputs, each time you needed a line too be written different of stop between each product
- I propose you to ask like '`name - price`' it's easier then to split and keep, beause if separator is a space you can't buy like for example "apple pie" ^^
- and in the print I add the the print of the list of products

If you need more, tell me in comment , It is possible to add for example a check at the input to verify of the typo name-price is verify, and then find the min/max is also quite easy with Map

```
//'Classic' method for min price without using complex notions
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
//iterate over the prices
for(Double price : products.values()){
    min = Math.min(min, price);
}
System.out.println("min is "+min);

//Second method with Stream (allow to iterate easliy)
double minBis = products.values().stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
System.out.println("mins is "+minBis);
```

Comment: Thank you very much azro :)
Although I never used HashMap before but I'll read about it to know how exactly it operates.

Comment: will it be different to get the max or min while using HashMap?

Comment: I've added 2 methods to get the min value, don't hesitate to accept the answer or vote up if you are satisfied